# Practices around usage of delimiter between words

Tags: java, string, unicode

We wanted to leverage redis string commands, which is just a simple key, value structure

We are trying to build a concept of cache around these string commands of redis. So, user of cache would pass a cachename , cacheversion (similar to SerialVersionID to track class defitions), key and value.

At the end, our normalized key is going to be cacheName + SEP + keyname + SEP+ cacheversion. where SEP is like a marker between each of the words so that we should later be able to derive keyname or cacheversion or cachename from the normalized keyname

Question is what can be right characters that can be used as SEP (marker) so that they dont clash with key/cacheversion/cachename?

Comment: In general, you want your separator to be a character that is not valid in the preceding component. Redis keys are just a sequence of bytes. If `keyname` is a Redis key, from a purely theoretical standpoint it's not possible to have an unambiguous delimiter -- unless you reorder your components so the `keyname` comes last.

Comment: @dnault i am introducing a separator here so that i will later be able to derive cachename/keyname/valueversion. What i am looking for is  that character which would usually not appear in any of the standard characters that user can possibly pass for cache/keyname/version